# HTML/CSS: The text is displayed in a reduced font size in the Chrome browser. How to disable this reducing?

Tags: html, css, font-size, font-scaling

Please see the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">       
    <style>
        p {
           font-size: 16px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione eligendi optio sapiente cumque quidem ad nihil repellat, qui illum suscipit necessitatibus, officiis illo. Molestias voluptas libero ratione qui, ut quibusdam!</p>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione eligendi optio sapiente cumque quidem ad nihil repellat, qui illum suscipit necessitatibus, officiis illo. Molestias voluptas libero ratione qui, ut quibusdam!<button>Read more></button></p>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Why the second paragraph is displayed in reduced font-size? How to turn this reducing off?

I noticed that this problem is only in the Chrome browser on my phone with system text size L, XL or XXL. In the Opera and Mi browsers paragraphs no problems, paragraps look same.

Comment: Please provide minimal example inside SO Snippet as your current code is working fine in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3whrea9n/)

Comment: maybe because you added the button inside the second <p> you can take it out of it

Comment: @ViH Please mention the browser and the browser version which you are using. There are default behavior of the browser when nesting an inline element. So we cannot reproduce your issue

Comment: Are you sure it is the second paragraph that is rendering with smaller font size here - and not the other way around? Because if the text of the first one was rendered larger, that could perhaps be a result of https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-size-adjust, I suppose?

Comment: I noticed that this problem is only in the Chrome browser on my phone with system text size L, XL or XXL. In the Opera and Mi browsers paragraphs no problems, paragraps look same.

Answer (score 0):

you can just give it a class and change it the way you like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">       
    <style>
        p {
           font-size: 16px;
        }

        .second_p{
         font-size: 18px;  /*or 18 anything you want*/
       }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione eligendi optio sapiente cumque quidem ad nihil repellat, qui illum suscipit necessitatibus, officiis illo. Molestias voluptas libero ratione qui, ut quibusdam!</p>
   <p class="second_p">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione eligendi optio sapiente cumque quidem ad nihil repellat, qui illum suscipit necessitatibus, officiis illo. Molestias voluptas libero ratione qui, ut quibusdam!<button>Read more></button></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I know about CSS classes. My question, why the two paragraphs have different font sizes on the phone screen (Chrome browser)?

Comment: when i tried it on Pc did inspect and phone version worked similarly for me with your first code,  i have tried it on chrome and opera, so i would say your answer is to change what you are reading your HTML file with

Comment: I noticed that this problem is only in the Chrome browser on my phone with system text size L, XL or XXL. In the Opera and Mi browsers paragraphs no problems, paragraps look same.

Comment: yup this makes sense, good luck with your work.

Answer (score 0):

16px is already by default in the browser so, there is no use of using `font-size: 16px;`
Try to use different font-size.

Comment: Yes, I know about 16px. My question, why the two paragraphs have different font sizes?

Comment: @ViH bro i didn't get this issue in my system maybe your browser is outdated try to update the browser

Comment: I noticed that this problem is only in the Chrome browser on my phone with system text size L, XL or XXL. In the Opera and Mi browsers paragraphs no problems, paragraps look same.

Comment: @ViH i tested your code on chrome browser and the result is `OK` there is no issue. I think you need to check your own pc & try to update chrome.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to give all the

elements a custom font size, you can simply style them the same as you did. You can try a different browser to see if the font-size issue is present there too.
In this specific case, it's not necessary to give 16px as the font size since it's the default size.

Comment: I just tried and noticed that this problem is only in the Chrome browser on my phone. In Mi browser paragraphs look same. Now how to make paragraphs look same in the Chrome browser?

Comment: In this case the problem may be due to CSS specificity rule, to make your font-style higher specific, you may try adding ID/CLASS to the required elements and use them as css selectors.  In CSS, rules with higher specificity take precedence over less specific rules. For example, after giving the <p> tag a class of 'my-class' , add ```p.my-class {
  font-size: 16px;
}  ```

Comment: I noticed that this problem is only in the Chrome browser on my phone with system text size L, XL or XXL. In the Opera and Mi browsers paragraphs no problems, paragraps look same.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).